# E/Camera2CameraImpl: Unable to configure camera 0, timeout! While React Native using Android Native camera

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, custom-view, react-native-bridge

I have implemented React Native bridging using a manager and module class in Ktolin. I am trying to access the native Android camera from React Native.

While trying to access the Android camera, I am facing a timeout issue.

*`E/Camera2CameraImpl: Unable to configure camera 0, timeout!`  *

```
E/unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by DeviceInfo
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:66)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.deviceinfo.DeviceInfoModule.invalidate(DeviceInfoModule.java:114)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:110)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:108)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:368)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

I will attach the manager class and context conversion to the fragmented activity.

```
// RNCameramanager.kt
package com.barcode.BarcodeScanner

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext


class ScannerBarcodeManager() : SimpleViewManager<ScannerBarcodeView>() {

 override fun getName() = "SFScannerBarcodeManager"


  override fun  createViewInstance(reactThemContext: ThemedReactContext): ScannerBarcodeView {
    return ScannerBarcodeView(reactThemContext)
  }
}
```

```
RNCameraView.kt
private val activity : FragmentActivity
  get()= getActivity(context)!!

private fun getActivity(activity: Context): FragmentActivity? {
     var context: Context? = activity
     while (context is ContextWrapper) {

      if (context is FragmentActivity) {
        Log.i("","inside")
        return context
      }
     context = context.baseContext
      }
    return null
  }
```

I am Expecting to access the camera from the Native. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.